# Does “slight future” have negative connotations?

Tags: connotation

I'm not an native English speaker and I see this word used in so many different contexts. Does "slight" come with negative connotations? It can be used negatively, but does it default to the negative? The movie "Her" marketed itself as being set "in the slight future". Is this supposed to refer to a many sci-fi movies' obsession with futuristic dystopias or does it literally just mean being nearer to now than "in the near future"?

Answer (score 3):

The 'slight' word can have a somewhat negative meaning (e.g. a 'slight effort' or a 'slight piece of work' might point to a lack of willingness), but I believe it's got a neutral connotation otherwise.

In the case of 'slight future', 'slight' just means 'near' or 'close'. No dystopia intended.